# While Loops for figuring out product (multiplication)?

Tags: python, while-loop

I cannot seem to figure this out. I'm supposed to write a while loop that will print the product (multiply) of the numbers between 1 and 50. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    x = 1
    total = 0
    while x <= 50:
       total = total * x
       x*=1
  print(total)

main ()
```

However, Python isn't printing anything. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `x*=1` does nothing (x times 1 equals x!), you meant `x+=1`.

Comment: Of course! It seems so obvious now! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 1
while x <= 50:
   x*=1
```

These statements are resulting in an infinite loop since multiplying `x` by one will never change it. Mathematically, `x * 1 -> x`.

In addition, if you're trying to multiply the numbers one through fifty, you don't want this:

```
total = 0
for some condition:
    total = total * something
```

since `total` will *forever* remain at zero. Mathematically, `x * 0 -> 0`.

The correct pseudo-code (which looks remarkably *like* Python) for getting the product of the numbers one through fifty is:

```
product = 1
for number = 1 through 50 inclusive:
    product = product * number
```

Changing your code to match that requires two things:

- `total` should start at one.
- you should *add* one to `x` in the loop rather than multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

x*=1 results in an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a `while` loop that never exits:

```
>>> import time
>>> x = 5
>>> while x < 10:
...     x*=1
...     print x
...     time.sleep(1)
... 
5
5
5
5
5
5
...
```

Your `x*=1` is multiplying the `x` value by 1, effectively doing nothing. Therefore, you are calling your `while` loop until `x` is 50, but `x` never changes. Instead, you might want to put `x+=1`, which will **add 1** to `x`.

In your code, you also want to change the `total = 0`, because we are not adding, we're multiplying. If `total` is 0, we are effectively calling `0*1*2*3*4...`, and since anything times 0 is 0, this is rendered useless. Therefore, we set `total` to `1`:

```
def main():
    x = 1
    total = 1 #Start off at 1 so that we don't do 0*1*2*3*4...
    while x <= 50:
       total = total * x
       x+=1
    print(total)

main()
```

This runs as:

```
>>> def main():
...     x = 1
...     total = 1 #Start off at 1 so that we don't do 0*1*2*3*4...
...     while x <= 50:
...        total = total * x
...        x+=1
...     print(total)
... 
>>> main()
```